# For each ‘CptS’ course, find the percentage of the students who failed the course. Assume a passing grade is 2 or above

Tags: sql, group-by, count

```
CREATE TABLE Course ( 
courseno   VARCHAR(7), 
credits    INTEGER NOT NULL, 
enroll_limit INTEGER, 
classroom   VARCHAR(10), 
PRIMARY KEY(courseNo), ); 

CREATE TABLE Student ( 
sID   CHAR(8),
sName   VARCHAR(30), 
major VARCHAR(10), 
trackcode   VARCHAR(10), 
PRIMARY KEY(sID), 
FOREIGN KEY (major,trackcode) REFERENCES Tracks(major,trackcode) );

CREATE TABLE Enroll ( 
courseno    VARCHAR(7), 
sID   CHAR(8), 
grade FLOAT NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (courseNo, sID), 
FOREIGN KEY (courseNo) REFERENCES Course(courseNo), 
FOREIGN KEY (sID) REFERENCES Student(sID) );
```

So far I've been able to create two seperate queries, one that counts the number of people who failes. And the other counts the number of people who passed. I'm having trouble combining these to produce the number of people passed / number of people failed. For each course.

```
SELECT course.courseno, COUNT(*) FROM course inner join enroll on enroll.courseno = course.courseno
WHERE course.courseno LIKE 'CptS%' and enroll.grade < 2
GROUP BY course.courseno;

SELECT course.courseno, COUNT(*) FROM course inner join enroll on enroll.courseno = course.courseno
WHERE course.courseno LIKE 'CptS%' and enroll.grade > 2
GROUP BY course.courseno;
```

The end result should look something like

```
courseno  passrate
CptS451   100
CptS323   100
CptS423   66
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using: mysql, sql-server, oraclce...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a conditional average for this:

```
select 
    courseno,
    avg(case when grade > 2 then 100.0 else 0 end) passrate
from enroll
where courseno like 'CptS%'
```

Comment: you beautiful beautiful person you.

Comment: Welcome @JakeGergen. If my answer properly responded to your question, then [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) by clicking the check sign... Thanks.